# Viewing tweets you have sent

Tags: twitter

How can I see the history of tweets I have sent?

Answer (score 2):

Your 3200 most recent Tweets are visible on your profile page: `https://twitter.com/{username}`.

Downloading your Twitter archive to allows you to browse a snapshot of your Twitter information, starting with your first Tweet. To download and view your Twitter archive:

1. Go to your [account settings](https://twitter.com/settings/account) by clicking on the **profile icon** at the top right of the page and selecting **Settings** from the dropdown menu.
2. Click **Request your archive**.
3. When your download is ready, we'll send an email with a download link to the confirmed email address associated with your Twitter account.
4. Once you receive the email, click the **Go now** button to log in to your Twitter account and download a .zip file of your Twitter archive.
5. Unzip the file and click **index.html** to view your archive in the web browser of your choice.